# how to view pdf files in spring web application without depending on browser plugin?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, pdf, web-applications

can someone guide me that how we can support viewing of pdf document through our spring web application without any dependency on browser as i am not willing to rely on my users having plugins installed?

While searching it on google I found that ﻿we can use Google Docs to provide a "view" link for PDFs.For example, http://bit.ly/oQCsTe is a (shortened) link to a PDF file. To easily allow users to view this in Google Docs, make a link like this: http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://bit.ly/oQCsTe

But I am looking for something else by which we will not need to use google docs and not rely on my users having plugins installed.

I watched a youtube vedio in which application storing the pdf files in database and showing it later. The url of that vedio is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uy_Uz08XM9g